# Значение "NULL" при обращении к объекту массива JSON (Java, Retrofit)

Tags: java, android, массивы, json, retrofit

Имею JSON по запросу - http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=track.getInfo&api_key=6c8dc87e402c8f96b8369f927ca0c1be&artist=cher&track=believe&format=json. Все работает, достаю нужные позиции. При обращении к массиву значений внутри поля получаю значение "NULL".
Где не так обращаюсь?
Сам код:

```
private void getTrackInfo(){
        Retrofit retrofit = NetworkClient.getRetrofitClient();
        MusicInterface musicInterface = retrofit.create(MusicInterface.class);
        Call callTrack = musicInterface.getTrackInfo("track.getInfo","6c8dc87e402c8f96b8369f927ca0c1be","Cher","Believe","json");

        try {
        Response<TrackInfo> responseTrackInfo = callTrack.execute();
        TrackInfo trackInfo = responseTrackInfo.body();

        final Track track = trackInfo.getTrack();

        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        //sb.append(track.getName());

        final Album album = track.getAlbum();

        sb.append(album.getArtist());
        sb.append(" - ");
        sb.append(album.getTitle());
        sb.append(", адрес картинки - ");
        sb.append(album.getImage().get(3).getText()); //строка возвращает значение "NULL" ????

        textView.setText(sb);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("caught IOException: " + e);
        }

    }
```

Класс Album выглядит так (на всякий случай привожу):

```
public class Album {

    private String artist, title;

    public String getArtist() {
        return artist;
    }

    public void setArtist(String artist) {
        this.artist = artist;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    private List<Image> image = null;

    public List<Image> getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(List<Image> image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
```

Comment: А на класс Image можно посмотреть?

Comment: Конечно, https://github.com/Dream-By/Parse_OK/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/parse_ok/Image.java

Comment: А album.getArtist(), что возвращает?

Comment: Значение поля Artist в Album

Comment: Именно на этот запрос и именно большими буквами? Просто java переводит в строку маленькими (`null`), а большими пишут в json - тогда получается, что его прислал сервер и это не ошибка вашего кода.

Comment: В ответе мне в пишется "null" в выводе в TextView. С ответом от сервера все в порядке. Для Debug'a я доработал функцию Get-запроса и запихнул весь ответ в String (идет отдельной опцией для проверки). Тут проблема вся - как обратитьсяк вложенному массиву? Думаю, что ответ где-то на поверхности.

Comment: Вложенному масиву чего? К какому именно у вас не получается обратиться?

Comment: В классе `Image` зачем аннотацию `@SerializedName("#text")` убрали? Так вы точно адрес не получите, потому что имя поля не совпадает с полем json и оно всегда будет `null`. В остальном ваш код рабочий, хоть и не правильно спроектированный в плане работы с сетью.

Comment: Аннотацию не убрал, а откомитал все старые исправления на гите :-). По поводу поля посмотрю, но есть мысль, что не там ищем... Делал неделю назад подобный запрос - все работало :-). Тут проблема в том, что массив Image находится внутри поля Album, а поле Album внутри поля Track. Короче, матрёшка получается. И вот как добраться до Image - не могу вкурить. Хотя да, код рабочий. А что не так при проектировании работы с сетью? По-моему гуд. Или в плане код-стала?

Comment: @Valeriy, массив Image находится внутри поля Album

Comment: *А что не так при проектировании работы с сетью?* - Слать запросы в главном потоке - очень плохая практика, это мешает отрисовке UI и "отзывчивости" интерфейса. Именно по этому Андроид кидает исключение `NetworkOnMainThreadException`, который вы заглушили через `StrictMode` (если память не изменяет, то этот трюк отвалится при сборке релизной версии и приложение будет падать с этой же причиной). Лучше сразу сделать, как положено, все запросы асинхронными - `execute` заменить на `enqueue` с колбэком или другими средствами вынести в фоновый поток и запросы, и все "длительно-тяжёлые" задачи

Comment: Хорошо. Этот момент учту при дальнейшем проектировании.

Answer (score 1):

Ларчик открылся неожиданно просто :-). В классе `Image` аннотацию `@SerializedName("#text")` вернул на место. Он стал выглядеть так:

```
public class Image {

    @SerializedName("#text")
    @Expose
    private String text;

    @SerializedName("size")
    @Expose
    private String size;

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public void setSize(String size) {
        this.size = size;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [#text = "+text+", size = "+size+"]";
    }

}
```

Класс `Album` также откорректировал:

```
public class Album {

    @SerializedName("artist")
    @Expose
    private String artist;

    @SerializedName("title")
    @Expose
    private String title;

    @SerializedName("image")
    @Expose
    private List<Image> image = null;

    public String getArtist() {
        return artist;
    }

    public void setArtist(String artist) {
        this.artist = artist;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public List<Image> getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(List <Image> image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [image = "+image+", artist = "+artist+", title = "+title+"]";
    }

}
```

Все работает.